# How to compare two maven builds from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

I would like to create a Jenkins job that can build 2 jars from the same maven project with different checkouts/branches and run test cases on both jars. And it will need to compare both results and generates a report from a single Jenkins job. I searched on google, but I couldn't find a good tutorial on how to do it. Does anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: First creating two jars from the same maven project sounds wrong...and what do you mean by checkouts/branches ? You have single maven project ? Can you give an pom file and explain what you like to achieve?

Comment: Say you have two contributors work on the same project, and we would like to run a functional test against two different version of their own branches and then compare the results. Is it possible to do this with CI instead of run two different jobs in CI and then compare them manually?